# Segmentation Fault upon call to GetSystemTime() function (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows

I'm having trouble dealing with a segmentation fault. The following sanity check throws one:

```
#include <windows.h>
int main()
{
    LPSYSTEMTIME startTime;
    GetSystemTime(startTime);
}
```

However, I've used the same code in a much larger program, and it runs without a problem. I've tried adding delays in various places in case the problem stems from some sort of multithreading within `GetSystemTime()`, but it did not solve the problem.

I'm compiling with MinGW-GCC in CodeBlocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LPSYSTEMTIME` is a pointer to a `SYSTEMTIME` structure. You don't initialize the pointer so it's pointing somewhere into the scenery, hence the access violation/seg fault.

In order to make the code work, you have to make sure the pointer points to a valid `SYSTEMTIME` structure. As per the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms724390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), Microsoft explicitly warns you that passing in NULL for the pointer will result in an access violation.

Comment: Thanks. I really dislike how Microsoft defines a different name for everything - it just makes everything more confusing.

Comment: In general when you see LP they mean Long Pointer... (long is historical).  Generally if you strip the LP from a type, you have the actual structure with allocation storage on the stack... e.g. `SYSTEMTIME`, then you'd pass `&startTime`

Answer (score 4):

You are using an uninitialized pointer. This works better:

```
#include <windows.h>
int main()
{
    SYSTEMTIME startTime;
    GetSystemTime(&startTime);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

LPSYSTEMTIME is a pointer, you need to either allocate memory or you need to loose the LP in LPSYSTEMTIME and call the function as in:

```
SYSTEMTIME startTime;
GetSystemTime(&startTime);
```

Answer (score 2):

`LPSYSTEMTIME` is a pointer to `SYSTEMTIME`, but it hasn't been initialized.

Try this instead:

```
SYSTEMTIME startTime = { 0 };
GetSystemTime(&startTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

For using  LPSYSTEMTIME you should write the following:

```
SYSTEMTIME  systemTime; //allocation of memory
printf("%p\n", &systemTime.wDay); // we can see address of wDay for example.
LPSYSTEMTIME st = &systemTime;
GetSystemTime(st);
printf("%d \n", st->wDay);  //display result 
printf("%d \n", (*st).wDay); //display the same result
```